# How to import CSS custom font from another website

Tags: html, css, custom-font

I'm trying to change font from my website, but that's doesn't work :/

My custom font url:  http://cdn.titanwar.net/fonts/coolvetica_rg/stylesheet.css

My Css:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Coolvetica Rg'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Step:1** Download the font.

**Step:2** Generate for cross-browsing.

- Internet Explorer (all versions) - .EOT;
- Safari (3.2+) - .TTF / .OTF;
- iPhone (3.1) - .SVG;
- Chrome (all versions) - .SVG (.TTF/.OTF added 25th Jan 2010);
- Firefox (3.5+) - .TTF/.OTF (.WOFF added 3.6);
- LOpera (10+) - .TTF/.OTF.

**Step:3** Upload font files on your website.

**Step 4:** Add your custom font files into CSS.

To add custom fonts to website use @fontface. Just add the following code into style.css

```
@font-face 
{
font-family: "Harabara Bold";
src: url("css/fonts/Harabara.eot");
src:
url("css/fonts/Harabara.woff") format("woff"),
url("css/fonts/Harabara.otf") format("opentype"),
url("css/fonts/Harabara.svg#filename") format("svg");
}
```

**Step5**: Start working

Now the custom font is added to website and you can use it:

```
h1 
{
font-family: 'Harabara Bold', Arial, sans-serif;
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A very basic question. Indeed one that needs to be addressed.

But Before that, the StyleSheet link you have provided, http://cdn.titanwar.net/fonts/coolvetica_rg/stylesheet.css -- This doesn't allow CORS right now. Means your local/other domain cannot import this css file via a Browser. Check your console and maybe try checking for your server for allowing CORS resources.

To use an external font on your website, you have to first import the same into your StyleSheet/CSS file. To Import a External StyleSheet, You can use

```
@import url('https://cdn.titanwar.net/fonts/coolvetica_rg/stylesheet.css');

html, body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Coolvetica Rg'
}
```

But you must be careful when importing. The @import function needs to be added on top of the StyleSheet itself. Means, before you start writing any codes on the css file.